# Update And Return Document In Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get updated documents. This is my original code and it successfully updates but doesn't return the document.

```
collection.update({ "code": req.body.code },{$set:  req.body.updatedFields}, function(err, results) {
                        res.send({error: err, affected: results});
                        db.close();
                    });
```

I used the `toArray` function, but this gave the error "Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback":

```
collection.update({ "code": req.body.code },{$set:  req.body.updatedFields}).toArray( function(err, results) {
                    res.send({error: err, affected: results});
                    db.close();
                });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

[`collection.update()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#update) will only report the number of documents that were affected to its own callback.

To retrieve the documents while modifying, you can use [`collection.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) instead (formerly [`.findAndModify()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findAndModify)).

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "code": req.body.code },
    { $set: req.body.updatedFields },
    { returnOriginal: false },
    function (err, documents) {
        res.send({ error: err, affected: documents });
        db.close();
    }
);
```

The `returnOriginal` option (or `new` with Mongoose) lets you specify which version of a found document (original [default] or updated) is passed to the callback.

`returnOriginal` was deprecated in version `3.6`. Use `returnDocument: "before" | "after"` for version `3.6` and later.

---

> Disclaimer: This answer currently refers to the Node.js Driver as of [version 3.6](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/). As new versions are released, check their documentation for possibly new deprecation warnings and recommended alternatives.

Comment: The docs suggest that it only does one document, not multiple --

Comment: it's deprecated now. use `collection.findOneAndUpdate` instead!

Comment: findOneAndUpdate seems to retrieve the document at the state it is before being modified. I think that the question was targetting to get the result object

Comment: setting the ```returnOriginal``` option to false returns the updated object

Comment: For the time being, I am using mongoose package with the version ^5.10.9, and can use the new: true instead of returnOriginal: false, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Also in Mongoose use `Mode.findOneAndUpdate`.

Answer (score 16):

The solution is to set: {returnOriginal: false}.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        whereObj,
        updateObj,
        {returnOriginal: false});
```

Comment: For the time being, I am using mongoose package with the version ^5.10.9, and can use the new: true instead of returnOriginal: false, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Could not find any way to update many and return the modified records in [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find), so I made a workaround.

At least one fault that I can find with below method is, you would not be able to tell if document is modified or already had the value that you are using:

```
function findAndUpdateMany(filter, updateOptions) {
  return collection.find(filter).project({_id: 1}).toArray()
    .then(function(matchingIds) {
      filter = {_id: {$in: matchingIds}}
      return collection.updateMany(filter, updateOptions)
    }).then(function() {
      return collection.find(filter).toArray()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late for the party but here's a simple 2022 solution to your question.
I'm using NestJS for this app

```
const updatedPainting: Partial<IGallery> = {
    imageAltTxt: updateGalleryDto.imageAltTxt,
    name: updateGalleryDto.name,
    dateCreated: updateGalleryDto.dateCreated,
    size: updateGalleryDto.size,
    description: updateGalleryDto.description,
    isFeatured: updateGalleryDto.isFeatured || false,
  };
  return await this.galleryModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id },
    { $set: { imageUrl, ...updatedPainting } },
    { returnDocument: 'after' },
  );
```

Comment: Great! This works with findOneAndUpdate, with the only update it does not work. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 3):

to get the updated doc when performing an update operation on one doc, use findOneAndUpdate() and in the options object, set returnDocument property to 'after'

`let options = {returnDocument: 'after'}`

`const upadatedDoc = collection.findOneAndUpdate({'your query'},{'your update'}, options)`

Answer (score 0):

With **Single** Field

```
 var filter = Builders<MongoDbModel>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Id, model.Id);
 var update = Builders<MongoDbModel>.Update.Set(u => u.Value, model.NewValue);

await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

With **Multiple** Fields

```
 var filter = Builders< MongoDbModel>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Id, model.Id);
 var update = Builders< MongoDbModel>.Update.Set(u => u.Field1, model.NewValue1)
                                            .Set(u => u.Field2, model.NewValue2);


 await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Answer (score -6):

Checkout the WriteResult object:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#writeresults-update

```
WriteResult result = collection.update({ "code": req.body.code },{$set:  req.body.updatedFields}, function(err, results) {
                    res.send({error: err, affected: results});
                    db.close();
                });
```

result should have something like:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

If you want the updated results, do another query with the primary key.

Comment: this only gives the stats, not the updated documents