# How to get Object ID after update the document using Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am updating my document using Node.js and I need to get that document id after updated. My code is below:

```
 var udata={
            name:name,
            company:company,
            position:position,
            mobile:mobile,
            email: email,
            landline: landline,
            url:url,
            postcode:postcode,
            address:address,
            profiletext:profiletext,
            biography:biography,
            updated_date:updateDate,
            file:file
        }
    db.f_card_details.update({userid:userid},{$set:udata},function(error,docum){
        if (!error) {
            if (docum) {
                console.log('document',docum);
                var edata=[{"id": docum._id}];
                var data={"statusCode": 200,"data":edata ,"message": "Your card details has been updated successfully"};
                res.send(data);
        }
}else{
            var data={"statusCode": 404,"error": "Not Found","message": "Your card details could not updated"};
            res.send(data);
}
                        })
```

Here I am not getting that document `object id` after update.

Comment: MongoDB create new _id each time when you create

Comment: MongoDB create _id to each object of collection when you create it by keyword new. var user = new User({ ... })

Answer (score 0):

From mongodb.com [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) -

"The update() method returns a WriteResult object that contains the status of the operation. Upon success, the WriteResult object contains the number of documents that matched the query condition, the number of documents inserted by the update, and the number of documents modified:

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })`
"

Comment: So how to get the `object id`.

Comment: I found a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747189/update-and-return-document-in-mongodb
The answer is - `collection.findOneAndUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

It will return old document, but you can set the `returnNewDocument : true` flag to make it return the new one.

So your code would be something like:

```
db.f_card_details.findOneAndUpdate({userid:userid},{$set:udata},function(error,docum){

    console.log(docum._id);
})
```