# Put function in NodeJS to manipulate MongoDB is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

Does someone know, how to implement a put function in NodeJS to manipulate a MongoDB collection?

I saw a lot of people using `app.get` or `app.post` in order to use `db.collection.updateOne()`, but I cant believe that this is the proper way of doing this.

Unfortunatly, when I am using `app.put` I am not getting an error, but still nothing changed in my collection. The data is still the same.

Please see my code below:

```
  app.put('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const details= {'_id' : new Object(id)};
    const user = {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password};

    db.collection('users').findOneAndUpdate(details,{$set: user},{new: true}, function (err, item) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occured'});
        } else {
            res.send(user)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're using an "object" inside an "object". You meant `db.collection('users').updateOne(details,{$set: user}...` since you already assigned the "query object" of `details` earlier in the code.

Comment: thanks for that hint. Unfortunatly the error still exist. When I am using Postman, and use "put" to this path and then give data in the body of the request, nothing changes at all...

Comment: It wasn't a hint but a clear error. What is the `req.params.id` value coming through as when you post? And what is the "error" exactly? It will be a different one now of course.

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting at all... I get the response as defined in my else{}, but when I am requesting another \get the user I wanted to modify is still the same... 

It comes as a string I gues... The request I am doing is: localhost:8000/user/5afdb8d8836baa20f3c23e10

Comment: Because you're using the wrong function. You want `findOneAndUpdate()`

Comment: Duplicate of - [Update And Return Document In Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747189/update-and-return-document-in-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks for this! But unfortunatly I already tried this and I still have the same issue...

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions. I made a close vote on your question because of the error I pointed out initially. Then you stated you expected the "updated document returned" hence I put the link. Then walked away.

Comment: Your error is not related to app.put, it is a mongodb issue, for sure. I've done several uses as this one with boot mongodb driver and mobgoosejs, it works fine, you may be connected to a different DB than you think.

Comment: Thanks for your help desoares. I am only having on db, with one collection, and I am doing all my other functions (get, post, delete) succesfully all on the same db.collection('users'). So I dont think that this is the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was that I defined the ID as an Object and not as an ObjectID.
Since MongoDB is Type sensetive it did not find the ID was "putting".

So instead of:

```
const details= {'_id' : new Object(id)};
```

It has to be:

```
const details= {'_id' : new ObjectID(id)};
```