# Increment field user.entries when I hit submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

any idea how to increment a field called 'entries' by 1 every time I hit the submit button and save it to the database (I am using MongoDB/mongoose)?

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
     const { id } = req.body;
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(id)
         .then(user => {
            return res.json(user.entries);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).json('Error getting entries');
            console.log(err);
        })

});
```

I tried the auto-incremet plugin, but I don't know if it works in this case, if so I couldn't quite place it in the right place. I also tried to add like

`User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$inc: {'entries': 1}}` but it only starts to work when I hit the but twice and on.

If anyone can help me It'd be a great help!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working. The only reason is that, `findByIdAndUpdate` returns the document before actually performing the update operation. If you want to get the increment value after the update operation, You might want to split the `findByIdAndUpdate` and try

```
User.update({_id: id},{$inc: {'entries': 1}}).then(() => {
    User.findOne({_id: id}).then( user =>{
        return res.json(user.entries);
    })
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json('Error getting entries');
    console.log(err);
})
```

You could also check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747189/update-and-return-document-in-mongodb) out by @Jonathan Lonowski if you still want to go with the `findByIdAndUpdate`.